# How do you make an ASP.Net 3.5 WebService accept AJAX PUT requests?

Tags: jquery, ajax, web-services, asp.net-3.5, put

I am not able to get a WebService in an ASP.Net 3.5 project to accept PUT requests.

Here is the AJAX call:

```
var url = '/MyService.asmx/UpdateObject';
var options = {
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    cache: false,
    type: "PUT",
    data: data ? ko.toJSON(data) : null
};

$.ajax(url, options);
```

In MyService.asmx, I have the following:

```
[WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet=true)]
public ButDto UpdateObject(ObjectDto myObject)
{
    //Do some stuff here

    return myObject;
}
```

However, I am getting the following error message:

> An attempt was made to call the method UpdateObject using a POST
>   request, which is not allowed.

If I remove ", UseHttpGet=true" from my web service declaration and I perform the same ajax call, I am getting the following error message:

> An attempt was made to call the method UpdateObject using a GET
>   request, which is not allowed.

So I am a bit baffled here.

**UPDATE**:

I also tried with dataType: "text", but the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), POST and GET are the only acceptable HTTP verbs with ScriptMethod.

As why you are getting errors. If you put a JSON array into the `data` property when you send the AJAX request, jQuery serializes it into a query string and sends that to the server. But that's not what ASP.NET is looking for. You need to pass jQuery a string of the JSON you want to use. Like:

```
var url = '/MyService.asmx/UpdateObject';
var options = {
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  // add charset for good measure
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: "{'id':2, 'name':'foobar'}"  // notice the quotes here
};

$.ajax(url, options);
```

You could use something `JSON.stringify()` from [JSON2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/) if you want to turn a Javascript object into a JSON string that is needed to complete the request.

If you want to read more take a look at http://encosia.com/3-mistakes-to-avoid-when-using-jquery-with-aspnet-ajax/ which has a lot of information about what some of the common mistakes are.

Comment: Thanks Steven for the information and for the good advices! I guess I could use POSTs to update entities. However, from what I've read, POSTs should be used to create entities and PUTs to update them. It is a shame that Microsoft's ScriptMethod does not accept PUT and DELETE requests. Is there another way to write an ASP.Net 3.5 web service that would accept PUT requests?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchamp In a RESTful setup, you're completely correct, PUT would be to replace/update an entity. I think it's acceptable to create/update an entity with a POST request as well. To accept PUT, I think you'd need to write something outside of a web service. Maybe a generic handler? But if you go that route, you'd lose some of the automatic serialization and mapping that the web service offers.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I finally used POSTs for everything concerning inserts, updates and deletes.